# What is the name of this sequence/progression?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

Does the following sequence form some special sequence/progression (such as arithmetic progression, geometric progression, hypergeometric progression, and more):
$$
p_k: = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}, k \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, \}?
$$

For example, does the ratio $$\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k} = \frac{\lambda}{k+1}$$
imply what sequence/progression it might be?

note:
$p_k$ is the probability mass function  (pmf) of the Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "special series or progression"?

Comment: E.g., arithmetic progression, geometric progression, hypergeometric progression, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The most notable fact about Poisson distribution is the following:

Consider $g_X(t) = \log E \exp (tX) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m_n t^n$,
which defines the *cumulants* $m_n$.

Then if $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$:

$$
m_n = \lambda
$$

Comment: "$\log E \exp t X$" might benefit from some parentheses.

Comment: this is done. the other ones are useless, and I don't like useless parentheses :-)